# Elasticsearch explicit sorting score

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field (say color) which can have one of four values (red, blue, yellow and green). I want to sort them such that red will have a score of 1 so all reds will be at the top, followed by blue with score of 2, yellow with score of 3 and so on.

How do I assign these manual scoring for sorting in elasticsearch?

Comment: please show us your mappings, queries , exceptions that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) feature, which will provide custom scoring functionality. You could replace **match_all** query with the one you needed.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "boost_mode": "replace",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "color": "red"
            }
          },
          "weight": 1
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "color": "blue"
            }
          },
          "weight": 3
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "color": "yellow"
            }
          },
          "weight": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 20,
  "from": 0
}
```

Comment: This is a good one but I've managed to achieve the same by adding sorting fields upon indexing... so the doc contains colorScore field with score of 1, 2 or 3 then I simply use those for sorting.

Comment: yes, it's just different approach, indexing time or query time.